# how to give separation between TableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I want to get lines of separation between every two table view cells, but not to create extra sections which I do not need.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to alternate the separator line, every two cells, instead of each one?

Comment: I only want to separate every two cells with a number of pixels height, background white color

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a Custom `TableViewCell`.
2. Contain your required views within a vertical `StackView`.
3. Add a `UIView` at the bottom of the `StackView` and set a height `constraint` to the size of the whitespace you require (i.e 10px).
4. Set a constraint for the height of the StackView to your required cell height (i.e. 70px)
5. Create a reference to the `StackView` height `Constraint`

---

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomSpace: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

}
```

[image]

In `viewDidLoad:`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as? CustomCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.bottomSpace.isHidden = true
            cell.stackViewHeight.constant = 70.0 //Normal cell height
        } else {
            cell.bottomSpace.isHidden = false
            cell.stackViewHeight.constant = 80.0 //Cell height + whitespace
        }

        cell.cellLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Updated my answer so that the visible cell height is the same for each cell, and the cell height is increased every other cell to show the whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

one way to do that is

```
// Inside UITableViewCell subclass
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10))
    }
```

or you can change offset from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom cell and add line as needed

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    lazy public  var line : UIView  = {
        let view  = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 0.5))
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        return view
        }()

    lazy public  var stackLine : UIStackView  = {



        let stackLine = UIStackView.init(arrangedSubviews: [self.line,self.line,self.line,self.line,self.line]) // line as you need
        stackLine.axis = .vertical
        stackLine.distribution = .fill
        stackLine.spacing = 1
        stackLine.alignment = .fill
        return stackLine
        }()


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(stackLine)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackLine.leadingAnchor .constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            stackLine.trailingAnchor .constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            stackLine.bottomAnchor .constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            stackLine.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5 * 0.5 + 1 * 4 ) // say 5 line * height of line + line space * number ofline -1
            ]
        )

    }

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't handle cell reuse very well since you will keep adding more and more stack views to each cell as the user scrolls.